# Make submit delay before POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, client, submit

I have button

```
   <UpdatePanel>
         <asp:Button CssClass="btn-send" runat="server"
              OnClick="SendMessage" Text="Send" />
    </UpdatePanel>
```

Server side method

```
protected void SendMessage(object sender, EventArgs e){...}
```

I need to make little delay and show progress bar animation before POST. I would like to use javascript (jquery) for this.

How to make this delayed submit
1) without server delay
2) without second button with client script, which click server button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this...

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="SendMessage" Text="Send"
   OnClientClick="return sendMessage(this);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var sendBtn = null;
  function sendMessage(btn){
    if(sendBtn==null){
      sendBtn = btn;
      window.setTimeout(function(){ sendBtn.click(); }, 1000);
      // DO YOUR VISUAL STUFF HERE
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

The idea is that the clicking of the button first stores the button object, sets a timeout to click the button, and then does the visual things you want to do.

Then after one second, the button is clicked again (this time not doing the timeout section)

(I have not had time to learn jquery yet, but I'm sure there is a simpler way to do this with it)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without jQuery, just using a regular Javascript [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3schools - see http://w3fools.com for the reasons why. You might have linked to a page that shows correct information, but the site contains a lot of incorrect and misleading information - and linking to the site in any way gives it credibility it does **not** deserve

Comment: Also, it's `setTimeout` and not `setTimeOut` (JavaScript is case-sensitive)

Comment: Thank-you for the knowledge. I did not know that. Although, in this case setTimeout is accurate. Thank-you for the correction on casing.

Comment: No worries - just spreading the knowledge... the more people who know the better (and if you search using Google, and have a Google account, you can block all results from them)

Comment: Javascript setTimeout() doesn't delay POST.

Comment: You don't post in your initial method, the method you call sets the time out to call the method containing your post. This delays the post.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87680.   If the page is accurate, it shouldn't matter if it came from w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the `onsubmit` of your form, and then when you have submit (your button is pressed) you open your wait message of the page. So you add this line on Page_Load()

```
Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"] = "return AllowFormToRun();";
```

and the javascript:

```
<script>
    function AllowFormToRun()
    {
        setTimeout(OpenWaitMsg, 10);
        return true; 
    }

    function OpenWaitMsg()
    {
        // open here the wait div 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Event.preventDefault()` on the submit button click to prevent the page from submiting on click.  Then start your progress animation, when its complete, call your form submit from the js.

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
  var form = this;
  e.preventDefault();
  function animation(total,callback){
    //perform your animation
    callback();
  };

  animation(100,function(){
    form.submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: actually, the form might be e.currentTarget..just did this off the top of my head, not tested..but it should give you an idea of how to get it done :)

Comment: generally it's fine, but form.submit() force page refresh and UpdatePanel doesnt' work

Comment: they shouldn't really have anything to do with one another, as form is scoped in the submit handler on the client side. it gets called when the animation is done.